# Retrieve details from blogs using C#

Tags: c#

I am searching for some kind of a method to retrieve data from different kinds of blogs programmatically using C# to post in one of my own ASP.Net pages. I want to get the most recent post, images in that post (if present), and the updated date of that post.

So, is there a common API kind of thing to connect to those blogs and retrieve that info from them once the blog URL is given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of blog engines out there and they do not share a common API. I think that trying to program one would be extremely difficult and maintaining it even more so. However, I think that you could just get an RSS feed from the blogs and parse the necessary data from that.

Here's one of the RSS libraries for .NET: http://www.rssdotnet.com/

Comment: Hi Ville, Thank you very much for your quick reply.. This is almost the type of answer I expected... :)

Comment: when I use RSS.Net it gives the total html formatted output as the description in a particular item in rss feed. Is there a way to extract only the text in that description tag?

Comment: I don't know. I'd suggest that you create (or better yet, search for) a new question for this problem.